# 10 connections limit for share on XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, network-share, shares

The scenario is as follows: Several users are working on local files ( each has its own file ). In the end all of them submit these files and they are copied into common shared folder. If this share is defined on XP pro computer the files are not saved sometimes because of 10 user limitation. Is there a way to overcome 10 connections limit to XP Pro shared folder?

Comment: Sounds like you need a *server*.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Home/Professional are limited to 10 concurrently users. If you need more then you'll need a server edition of windows, or another alternative like a NAS, samba on Linux etc.

Comment: Is there any way to increase this limit?

Comment: @SparcU no, like both answers said, you'll need to use something else than windows home/professional.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to overcome 10 connections limit to XP Pro shared folder?

Use a server for server tasks. That will solve your problem.

Comment: One issue I found was that every time the files are copied to the share each computer opens more than one connection so the limit is used up when 3 computers are copying the files. This seems very strange to me.

Comment: Like I said. If you're using a machine as a server, run a server OS on it.